# InvalidateLater in shiny app is increasing memory footprint in browser

Tags: shiny, browser, memory-leaks

I created a shiny dashboard that is running 24/7. It uses the `invalidateLater()` function to refresh every 20 seconds, however I noticed my browser receiving an "out of memory" error after running it for a couple of days and when I checked the memory footprint of this app was multiple gigabytes.

For example this is what my footprint looks like when just running the script:
[image]

But after letting the script run for a few hours it looks like this already:
[image]

The code is fairly sizable but I use the following packages:

```
library(shiny) # For creating the web application
library(shinydashboard) # For the UI
library(data.table) # For processing the data
library(readxl) # For reading .xlsx files
library(billboarder) # For plotting graphs
library(tools) # For file_path_sans_ext function
library(htmlwidgets)
```

And my refresh looks like this:

```
observe({
    invalidateLater(20*1000, session)
})
```

Server:

```
rv <- reactiveValues()

observe({
    invalidateLater(20*1000, session)
    refresh()
    shell("cd ../../Onedrive/Sharepoint folder && del /s /q *-LEY*.xlsx")
    list <- list.files(path = "../../Onedrive/Sharepoint folder", pattern = ".xlsx", recursive = T)
    for (i in 1:length(list)) {
      assign(basename(file_path_sans_ext(list[i])), 
             as.data.table(read_xlsx(paste0("../../Onedrive/Sharepoint folder/", list[i]))))
    }
    rv$shift <- fcase(between(Sys.time(), as.POSIXct("7:00:00", format = "%H:%M:%S"), as.POSIXct("14:29:59", format = "%H:%M:%S")), "Morning",
                      between(Sys.time(), as.POSIXct("14:30:00", format = "%H:%M:%S"), as.POSIXct("22:59:59", format = "%H:%M:%S")), "Afternoon",
                      default = "Night")
    Inbound_FP_Trucks_Boxes[is.na(Inbound_FP_Trucks_Boxes)] <- 0
    rv$Inbound_FP_Trucks_Boxes <- Inbound_FP_Trucks_Boxes
    Automatic_validation[is.na(Automatic_validation)] <- 0
    rv$Automatic_validation <- Automatic_validation
    Productivity[is.na(Productivity)] <- 0
    rv$Productivity <- Productivity
    rv$Special_comments <- Special_comments
    rv$`5S_Projects` <- `5S_Projects`
    `5S_Checklist`[is.na(`5S_Checklist`)] <- 0
    rv$`5S_Checklist` <- `5S_Checklist`
    rv$HR_Topics <- HR_Topics
    rv$Product_care <- Product_care
    rv$Product_care_images <- Product_care_images
  })
  
  output$TOTAL_DAY_TRUCKS_text <- renderText({})
  output$TOTAL_DAY_TRUCKS <- renderText({})
  output$TOTAL_DAY_BOXES_text <- renderText({})
  output$TOTAL_DAY_BOXES <- renderText({})
  output$CURRENT_SHIFT_TRUCKS_text <- renderText({})
  output$CURRENT_SHIFT_TRUCKSS <- renderText({})
  output$CURRENT_SHIFT_BOXES_text <- renderText({})
  output$CURRENT_SHIFT_BOXES <- renderText({})
  output$CURRENT_SHIFT_TRUCKS <- renderBillboarder({})
  output$`UI_AUTOMATIC_VALIDATION_W-1` <- renderUI({
    output$`AUTOMATIC_VALIDATION_W-1_text` <- renderText({})
    output$`AUTOMATIC_VALIDATION_W-1` <- renderText({})
    tagList(
      textOutput("AUTOMATIC_VALIDATION_W-1_text") %>% tagAppendAttributes(class = "left"),
      span(textOutput("AUTOMATIC_VALIDATION_W-1") %>% tagAppendAttributes(class = "right"), style=paste0("color:", var))
    )
  })
  output$UI_AUTOMATIC_VALIDATION_MONTHLY <- renderUI({
    output$AUTOMATIC_VALIDATION_MONTHLY_text <- renderText({})
    output$AUTOMATIC_VALIDATION_MONTHLY <- renderText({})
    tagList(
      textOutput("AUTOMATIC_VALIDATION_MONTHLY_text") %>% tagAppendAttributes(class = "left"),
      span(textOutput("AUTOMATIC_VALIDATION_MONTHLY") %>% tagAppendAttributes(class = "right"), style=paste0("color:", var))
    )
  })
  output$`UI_PRODUCTIVITY_D-1` <- renderUI({
    output$`PRODUCTIVITY_D-1_text` <- renderText({})
    output$`PRODUCTIVITY_D-1` <- renderText({})
    tagList(
      textOutput("PRODUCTIVITY_D-1_text") %>% tagAppendAttributes(class = "left"),
      span(textOutput("PRODUCTIVITY_D-1") %>% tagAppendAttributes(class = "right"), style=paste0("color:", var))
    )
  })
  output$UI_PRODUCTIVITY_MONTHLY <- renderUI({
    output$`PRODUCTIVITY_MONTHLY_text` <- renderText({})
    output$PRODUCTIVITY_MONTHLY <- renderText({})
    tagList(
      textOutput("PRODUCTIVITY_MONTHLY_text") %>% tagAppendAttributes(class = "left"),
      span(textOutput("PRODUCTIVITY_MONTHLY") %>% tagAppendAttributes(class = "right"), style=paste0("color:", var))
    )
  })
  output$PRODUCTIVITY_BUDGET <- renderText({})
  output$AREA_MANAGER_TOPICS <- renderTable({}, colnames = F, sanitize.text.function=identity)
  output$PRODUCT_CARE_TRAINING <- renderTable({}, colnames = F)
  output$PRODUCT_CARE_IMAGE <- renderUI({})
  output$`5S` <- renderTable({}, colnames = F)
  output$HR_TOPICS <- renderTable({}, colnames = F)
  output$Stars <- renderUI({})
  output$STARS_LAST_UPDATE <- renderText({})
```

Comment: can u post more code of what is actually you're doing?

Comment: @PorkChop added server part of the code. The rest is only UI

Comment: You have a lot going on inside an observer, you should ever do small operations using it. First I would remove all the outputs and `render` functions from it

Comment: I'd like to generalize @PorkChop's comment: You should never nest `reactive`, `observe` or `renderXXX` functions inside each other. Usually they belong on the top level of your `server` function.

Comment: All the outputs and renders are outside my observe... Maybe I am not following. My observe ends after assigning the tables to my reactiveVal